# Getting error in AVL tree

Tags: c, data-structures

I am getting error in the creation of my AVL tree,the output of my code is  giving infinite loop every time.

In the following code `mknode` function is used to create a `node` and `lr,rl,right,leftfunctions` are used to do the required rotations whereas insert function is used to insert the values in the AVL tree and then perform the rotations as per the requirement.

I had checked my code many times but was unable to find the mistake.

Please help me.

```
struct node
{int a;
struct node *left,*right;
int height;
}*root;
 int bal_factor(struct node*);
 int height(struct node*);
 int greater(int,int);
 struct node*mknode(int);
 struct node*insert(struct node*,int);
 struct node*left(struct node*);
 struct node*right(struct node*);
 struct node*lr(struct node*);
 struct node*rl(struct node*);
 void inorder(struct node*);
 void main()
{
printf("avl tree\n");
root=insert(root,30);
root=insert(root,40);
root=insert(root,20);
root=insert(root,10);
root=insert(root,45);
inorder(root);
}
void inorder(struct node *temp)
{
if(temp==NULL)
    return;
inorder(temp->left);
printf("%d\t",temp->a);
inorder(temp->right);
}
int bal_factor(struct node *temp)
{
if(temp==NULL)
    return 0;
else
 return(height(temp->left)-height(temp->right));
}
int height(struct node *temp)
{
if(temp==NULL)
    return 0;
else
    return greater(height(temp->left),height(temp->right))+1;

}
int greater(int a,int b)
{
if(a>b)
    return a;
else
    return b;
}
struct node* mknode(int t)
{
struct node *temp;
temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
temp->a=t;
temp->left=temp->right=NULL;
temp->height=1;
return temp;
};
struct node*right(struct node *temp)
{struct node* temp1;
temp1=temp->left;
temp->left=temp1->right;
temp1->right=temp;
temp1->height=greater(height(temp1->left),height(temp1->right))+1;
temp->height=greater(height(temp->left),height(temp->right))+1;
return temp1;
};
struct node* left(struct node *temp)
{   struct node* temp1;
temp1=temp->right;
temp->right=temp1->left;
temp1->left=temp;
temp1->height=greater(height(temp1->left),height(temp1->right))+1;
temp->height=greater(height(temp->left),height(temp->right))+1;
return temp1;
};
struct node* lr(struct node *temp)
{
temp->left=left(temp->left);
return right(temp);
};
struct node* rl(struct node *temp)
{
temp->right=right(temp->right);
return left(temp);
};
struct node* insert(struct node *temp,int t1)
{
if(temp==NULL)
    return mknode(t1);
if(t1<temp->a)
    temp->left=insert(temp->left,t1);
else
    temp->right=insert(temp->right,t1);
int t;
temp->height=greater(height(temp->left),height(temp->right))+1;
t=bal_factor(temp);
if(t>1&&t1<temp->left->a);
return right(temp);
if(t1<-1&&t1>temp->right->a);
return left(temp);
if(t<-1&&t1<temp->right->a);
return rl(temp);
if(t>1&&t1>temp->left->a);
return lr(temp);

return temp;
}
```

Comment: Please learn how to indent your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
  if (t>1 && t1<temp->left->a);
  return right(temp);
  if (t1<-1 && t1>temp->right->a);
  return left(temp);
  if (t<-1 && t1<temp->right->a);
  return rl(temp);
  if (t>1 && t1>temp->left->a);
  return lr(temp);
```

You probably wanted this:

```
  if (t>1 && t1<temp->left->a)
    return right(temp);
  if (t1<-1 && t1>temp->right->a)
    return left(temp);
  if (t<-1 && t1<temp->right->a)
    return rl(temp);
  if (t>1 && t1>temp->left->a)
    return lr(temp);
```

Note the absence of `;` after the lines starting with `if`.

Unrelated:

```
temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

should be written

```
temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

You don't cast the return value of `malloc` in C.

Comment: if we use    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));   than it would return void pointer which has to be typecasted into struct node  type pointer.

Comment: @Harsh for an explanation [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: by the way thank u for helping me now my code is generating the right output

Comment: @Harsh I almost fogot: you should indent your code correctly.

Comment: Actually sir I don't know how to write a code with proper indentation,that's why there was a problem with my code.Sir I will be highly grateful to you if you tell me how to write a proper indented code.